# Dynamically get the type for the function returned from a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-i18next

So, I am writing a translation wrapper for the react translation hook to replace some text on the app. I have a `translationWrapper` function that returns a `customTFunc` as shown below:

```
export const translationWrapper = (translationName: 'FormValidations' | 'Notifications' | 'Configuration') => {
    const { t } = useTranslation(translationName);

    const customTFunc = (translationText: Normalize<typeof FormValidations>) => {
        const translatedText = t(translationText);
        if (someCondition) {
            return translatedText.replace("oldText", 'newText');
        }
        return translatedText;
    };

    return { customTFunc };
};
```

Usage:

```
const { customTFunc } = translationWrapper('FormValidations');
const translatedText = customTFunc('form_validation_translation')
```

For the `customTFunc` I want to have its argument `translationText` dynamically typed based on what was passed to the `translationWrapper`.

So, if the `translationName` is "Notifications"; I want the `translationText` to be `Normalize<typeof Notifications>`

Comment: Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgldvN)?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made clear what do you mean by "dynamically typed based on..." but the general approach would be:

```
export const translationWrapper = <T extends 'FormValidations' | 'Notifications' | 'Configuration'>(translationName: T) => {
    const { t } = useTranslation(translationName);

    const customTFunc = (translationText: Normalize<typeof FormValidations>) => { // Here you can use type 'T', for example Normalize<T>
        const translatedText = t(translationText);
        if (someCondition) {
            return translatedText.replace("oldText", 'newText');
        }
        return translatedText;
    };

    return { customTFunc };
};
```

First you define a type parameter name `T`, which is extended from a union, then you can use `T` anywhere you want within the function.